# Measure network traffic programmatically on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, networking

I'm interested in measuring the network traffic for my application. Ideally I would need to separate wireless from 3G network traffic. I can't seem to find any API that gets this information; however I see that there is at least one app in the AppStore that does something close (they actually sum up the traffic for the entire phone).

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please explain us how? Regards,

Comment: Hi, i see your solution below, but I have a question: have you accomplished your project using getifaddrs? Have you figured out multi aplication problem? So you can separate application whith one use how many data?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've found one approximate solution: `getifaddrs` can be used to get statistics on network usage.

One advantage is that it can get separate statistics for Wi-Fi and WWAN interfaces.

A disadvantage is that on multi-tasking devices those interfaces may be used by multiple applications and the statistics are cumulated.

Comment: Do you have some sample code, I have tried and could get IP address but no stats data....!!

Answer (score 6):

I also was looking for solution and found it here:
[iPhone Data Usage Tracking/Monitoring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7946699/iphone-data-usage-tracking-monitoring?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Please take a look this post, it provides all info that you need.