# How to know about network details and uses in ios sdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I have a requirement for my new app, where i have to calculate Data uses, Type of Network,remaining uses and all like Data Usage app does. Can any one help me for the same How to i start. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want to know the type of network

look at [Reachability](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) , it's official!

The Reachability sample application demonstrates how to use the SystemConfiguration framework to monitor the network state of an iPhone or iPod touch. In particular, it demonstrates how to know when IP can be routed and when traffic will be routed through a Wireless Wide Area Network (WWAN) interface such as EDGE or 3G.

Comment: Thanks adali, i want to know data uses and all the info below app does http://itunes.apple.com/in/app/data-usage/id386950560?mt=8

Comment: look at this thread  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7946699/iphone-data-usage-tracking-monitoring

Comment: and maybe this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4313358/measure-network-traffic-programmatically-on-iphone

Comment: +1 for your efforts Adali thanks... Searching for a tutorial/details on same.